# Why PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST is 9000

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

When implementing a GCM Client, I found we use this constant:

```
PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST is 9000
```

I'm new to programming, and maybe this is obvious, but I couldn't find information about it. Is this just a random number? Could I use other number?

Comment: I think it's just a number that you assign like the other resolution_requests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it can be any number - as long as it is unique to that activity.

Answer (score 9):

Please see the following:

[Link to Google documentation...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))

It appears that the 9000 is the requestCode for `startActivityForResult()`.

Once the `startActivityForResult()` finishes, it passes its result to the `onActivityResult()` and since you can have many `startActivityForResult()` running at the same time, it becomes necessary for `onActivityResult()` to identify **which** `startActivityForResult` generated that result.

The 9000 is passed into a built-in android `startActivityForResult()` and subsequently the `onActivityResult()` method in the `GooglePlayServicesUtil` class so we cannot see the 9000 being passed around but that is basically how it works.